# How to stop vscode beautify or prettier from preserving newlines when formatting javascript code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I want to remove all the newlines/extra lines when I save the code. I found this settings in Atom but not in VSCode. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the VSCode setting `html.format.preserveNewLines` to `false`. It will be recognized by Beautify, but works only for HTML files.

The alternative to apply the setting for all files recognized by Beautify is to add a file named `.jsbeautifyrc` at the root of the workspace, with the following content:

```
{
   "preserve_newlines": false
}
```

Also, the VSCode setting `editor.formatOnSave` should be set to `true`. To do it you can create the file `.vscode/settings.json` with the next content:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

The `settings.json` file, located at the `.vscode` folder in the root of the workspace, allows to configure the VSCode settings to be applied for the current workspace.

Comment: it works for html file but not for js files.it still leaves one empty line.

Comment: Try disabling Prettier, and just let Beautify enabled, as they may cause conflict. Also, it seems that only Beautify supports that setting.

Answer (score -2):

You can also set `Trim Final New lines` to on and `set Max Preserve New lines` to your need.

[image: Vs code settings image]